# Re-initialize linked list to be empty using recursion

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that initializes a linked list using recursion. My code below does not work. The program crashes when I am trying to insert another item in the list.

```
void r_make_empty(struct Node* &p){
Node *temp;
if(p == NULL){
return;
}
temp = p;
r_make_empty(p->next);
delete temp;
}
```

The function call is `r_make_empty(head);`

The insert function:

```
void r_insert(Node* &p,const Item &entry){

    if(exists(entry)==true){
        r_remove(entry);
    }

if (p == NULL || entry<p->data){

    p = get_node(entry, p);

}else{

r_insert(p->next, entry);
}

}
```

The `get_node` function:

```
Node* get_node(const Item &entry, Node* link){ 

    Node *temp;

    temp= new Node;
    temp->data = entry;
    temp->next = link;

    return temp;

}
```

The `remove` function:

```
void List:: r_remove(Node* &p, const Item &entry){

Node *prev;
Node *temp;

if(exists(entry)==true){ 

   if(first->data == entry){ 

    temp = first; 
    first= first->next; 
    delete temp; 
   }else{

   prev = first; 

   if(prev->next != NULL && prev->next->data !=entry){

    r_remove(prev->next, entry);
   }

   temp= prev->next; 
   prev->next = temp->next; 
   delete temp; 

   }
}

}
```

Comment: `r_make_empty()` does not set `p = NULL`, so `head` is not a valid pointer anymore after calling `r_make_empty(head);` And FYI, using recursion to clear a linked list is a very bad idea, as it can easily cause a stack overflow for a long list.  Always clear a linked list using a simple traversal loop instead

Comment: Also, your `r_insert()` function traverses the list multiple times, which is very inefficient for an insert operation. Inserts and removals on a linked list are supposed to be efficient, but yours are not.

Comment: True. When you call the r_make_empty, the pointer passed to is never set to NULL. Using the same (dangling) pointer in the the subsequent steps to insert new entries may crash.

Comment: You're right guys the r_make_empty() function was not setting p to NULL, if figured it out, thanks!